# Mocked object with fixed class name pollutes my following tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In the framework we're using, there are several operations that are performed considering the class name.
So, while testing, I have to force the mock classname, doing something like this:

```
$this->getMock('Model', $methods, array($config), 'ModelFoobars');
```

Sadly I just found out that doing this will pollutes my following tests. This is very strange, since there is no internal cache (singleton pattern) in the objects I'm curently testing.
However, if I debug my test, I can find that my `$model` variable is an instance of PhpUnit, even if it was created using a `new` syntax!

```
$classname = 'ModelFoobars';
$model     = new $classname();
```

I have no opcode cache, nor anything like that. This is really driving me crazy, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and debugging (and I really mean **a lot**), I finally found the problem.
When you create a new mocked object, under the hood PhpUnit is dynamically creating new code, then it evals it.
By default, PhpUnit creates random class names, so you usually don't have any problems; however, if you force the class name, you can have "funny" results. Since the code is evaled, the class is pushed into the global scope!
This means that once you created the mock, you can't create another one with the same name: you are stuck using the first one.

The only solution I found is to avoid using fixed class names and always rely on the random ones.